# Restarting systemd service on path change takes a long time

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I have a systemd Ubuntu service of type `simple`, call it `foo.service`, with a Python script that is being executed, in `ExecStart`.

Then another service, of type `oneshot`, call it `foo-restart.service` that is executing `/usr/bin/systemctl restart foo.service`.

Lastly, a `PathChanged` directive in a separate file, `foo-restart.path`, pointing to my Python script.

The idea is that the service will get restarted as I update the file - which is happening, but it takes a while, and a `journalctl -fu foo.service` reveals:

```
Oct 08 22:45:14 Vpn445 systemd[1]: Stopping Foo...
Oct 08 22:45:58 Vpn445 python3[2686278]: Yay
Oct 08 22:46:44 Vpn445 systemd[1]: foo.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Oct 08 22:46:44 Vpn445 systemd[1]: foo.service: Killing process 2686278 (python3) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 08 22:46:44 Vpn445 systemd[1]: foo.service: Killing process 2686305 (python3) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 08 22:46:44 Vpn445 systemd[1]: foo.service: Killing process 2689506 (python3) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 08 22:46:44 Vpn445 systemd[1]: foo.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Oct 08 22:46:44 Vpn445 systemd[1]: foo.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Oct 08 22:46:44 Vpn445 systemd[1]: Stopped Foo.
Oct 08 22:46:44 Vpn445 systemd[1]: Started Foo.
```

How can I make this process quicker, what command should I trigger to make sure the service will get stopped and restarted much quicker, and lastly, would a reload be enough.

I've changed foo's type to `oneshot` too, ran `systemctl daemon-reload` and restarted the service, no luck.

I can see what the issue is, as I log in a message every 10 secs. The stop process starts yet the script still runs until it gets stopped forcefully:

```
Oct 08 23:38:28 Vpn445 systemd[1]: Stopping Foo...
Oct 08 23:38:33 React python3[2692568]: After change
Oct 08 23:38:43 React python3[2692568]: After change
```

Comment: Does your Python script capture the stop-sigterm and exit? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully

Comment: No, it doesn't! Should I just write a function to handle that then.